# Run-time error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone point out what's wrong in my code as I'm getting a...

> Run-time error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set

on this line in the code below

> Loop While c2.Address <> e

```
Dim Cell As Range
Dim SrchRng2 As Range
Dim c2 As Range, e As String

'Check each row in column - if BLUE text (set by CF) change to #N/A
For Each Cell In Intersect(Columns("E"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If Cell.DisplayFormat.Font.ColorIndex = 5 Then Cell.Value = "#N/A"
Next
On Error GoTo NoBlueText
'Search column E for cells with #N/A and clear cells across columns E:G in row
Set SrchRng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("E2", ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set c2 = SrchRng2.Find("#N/A", LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not c2 Is Nothing Then
    e = c2.Address
Do
            ActiveSheet.Range("E" & c2.Row & ":G" & c2.Row).Cells.ClearContents
        Set c2 = SrchRng2.FindNext(c2)
    Loop While c2.Address <> e
End If

NoBlueText:
```

Comment: You do not have the initial `Do` to denote the start of the loop.

Comment: Sorry I did have the Do in the code, but forgot to type it while transferring to this page. The Error still exists

Comment: You will need to deal with the fact that at the end there will not be anymore to find as you clear them out.  You will need to have a test if C2 is nothing or is <> to e and set a boolean as the item the loop tests.

Comment: Doesn't the Loop While c2.Address <> e achieve this. Sorry I'm very new to VBA

Comment: No, As you use the find next, without the clear data it would eventually return to the top or first cell as it loops through them all.  But as you are clearing the data as you go it will eventually not find anymore and thus c2 will be nothing and nothing has no address.  You could also use Union to create the whole range then after the loop do the clearContents on the unioned range.  Then your loop logic will work properly as you are not clearing anything till after the loop.

Comment: @BruceWayne, just to notice BradleyS icon...you may want to suit him!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you're first placing "#N/A" in cells and then look for them, wouldn't it be simpler to act directly at the first stage?

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .Range("E2", .Cells(.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp))
        For Each cell In .Cells
            If cell.DisplayFormat.Font.ColorIndex = 5 Then cell.Resize(, 3).ClearContents
        Next
    End With
End With
```